# Is the "expression problem" solvable in F#?

Tags: f#

I've been watching an interesting [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Ralf-Lmmel-Advanced-Functional-Programming-Type-Classes) in which type classes in Haskell are used to solve the so-called "expression problem".  About 15 minutes in, it shows how type classes can be used to "open up" a datatype based on a discriminated union for extension -- additional discriminators can be added separately without modifying / rebuilding the original definition.

I know type classes aren't available in F#, but is there a way using other language features to achieve this kind of extensibility?  If not, how close can we come to solving the expression problem in F#?

Clarification:  I'm assuming the problem is defined as described in the [previous video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Ralf-Laemmel-Advanced-Functional-Programming-The-Expression-Problem/)
in the series -- extensibility of the datatype and operations on the datatype with the features of code-level modularization and separate compilation (extensions can be deployed as separate modules without needing to modify or recompile the original code) as well as static type safety.

Comment: You should probably clarify what exactly you mean by *expression problem*. There are differing opinions on exactly which parts of Wadler's problem statement are part of the *expression problem* proper, and which are further restrictions *on top of* the expression problem. For example, Martin Odersky, in *his* paper, considers modular typechecking as part of the expression problem, which actually means that Haskell *does not* solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jörg pointed out in a comment, it depends on what you mean by *solve*. If you mean *solve* including some form of type-checking that the you're not missing an implementation of some function for some case, then F# doesn't give you any *elegant* way (and I'm not sure if the Haskell solution is elegant). You may be able to encode it using the SML solution mentioned by kvb or maybe using one of the [OO based solutions](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~madst/ecoop04/index.html).

In reality, if I was developing a real-world system that needs to solve the problem, I would choose a solution that doesn't give you full checking, but is much easier to use.

A sketch would be to use `obj` as the representation of a type and use reflection to locate functions that provide implementation for individual cases. I would probably mark all parts using some attribute to make checking easier. A module adding application to an expression might look like this:

```
[<Extends("Expr")>]  // Specifies that this type should be treated as a case of 'Expr'
type App = App of obj * obj

module AppModule = 
  [<Implements("format")>] // Specifies that this extends function 'format'
  let format (App(e1, e2)) =
    // We don't make recursive calls directly, but instead use `invoke` function
    // and some representation of the function named `formatFunc`. Alternatively
    // you could support 'e1?format' using dynamic invoke.
    sprintfn "(%s %s)" (invoke formatFunc e1) (invoke formatFunc e2)
```

This does not give you any type-checking, but it gives you a fairly elegant solution that is easy to use and not that difficult to implement (using reflection). Checking that you're not missing a case is not done at compile-time, but you can easily write unit tests for that.

Comment: Those "OO solutions" require recompiling preexisting code (see section 2 of the paper), so they don't solve the Expression Problem as stated by Wadler. One may not have the source code of the API that is to be extended, and perhaps only the interfaces.

Comment: Interestingly, your solution is Greenspunning "rule-based programming" as seen in term-rewrite languages like Mathematica. However, I'd stress that the expression problem is a purely academic challenge that I have never needed to solve in 30 years of programming.

Answer (score 3):

See Vesa Karvonen's comment [here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2232#comment-31278) for one SML solution (albeit cumbersome), which can easily be translated to F#.

Comment: Not so easily: it requires recursive types which F# does not support. And it is not clear to me how that is solving the expression problem, e.g. how do I add `Pow` to the example without rewriting everything?

Comment: @JonHarrop - Not sure what you mean by "it requires recursive types which F# does not support" (?!) - a direct transliteration of the SML code works as expected.  As to how to add a Pow - either add a new case to the `num` type and handle it in the `numEval` and `numToString` functions (leaving everything else unchanged), or else add a new case directly to the `t` type and handle it in the `eval` and `toString` functions (again leaving everything else unchanged).

Comment: "a direct transliteration of the SML code works as expected". I get the error "the resulting type would be infinite when unifying 'a and 'a lam". "either add a new case to the num type". The whole point of the expression problem is that you're not allowed to edit the original code. You must extend it externally. Consequently, I don't think that code solves the expression problem at all. I think he's just hard-coded one particular version from Garrigue's paper and missed the point of the exercise.

Comment: @JonHarrop - `type 'e lam = ABS of string * 'e | APP of 'e * 'e | VAR of string` works for me.  Vesa's approach allows the `lam`, `num`, and `cons` types to be compiled separately, and then tied together with a small amount of boilerplate into the type `t`.  It seems quite clearly to be addressing the expression problem to me.

Comment: I get the type error at the code `eval ((s, x)::e) b` in the body of the `lamEval` function. Does this code even compile as SML? The expression problem is about extending an existing type A to create a new type B in a way that lets you reuse existing functions over A using values of type B directly. Garrigue's OCaml accomplishes this using polymorphic variants, e.g. `var` is a subtype of `'a lambda`. Karvonen's SML does not accomplish this, IMO. Every time you add a new type constructor you must wrap every single function, i.e. write asymptotically more code.

Comment: Note that `eval1` in Garrigue's paper has the type `(string * ('a lambda as 'a)) list -> 'a -> 'a`. That is a recursive type (aka rectype). OCaml supports those. AFAIK, Standard ML and F# do not. The type error I'm getting from F# is telling me that it is trying to create a recursive type (unify `'a` with `'a lam`).

Answer (score 2):

> I know type classes aren't available in F#, but is there a way using other language features to achieve this kind of extensibility?

I do not believe so, no.

> If not, how close can we come to solving the expression problem in F#?

The expression problem is about allowing the user to augment your library code with both new functions and new types without having to recompile your library. In F#, union types make it easy to add new functions (but impossible to add new union cases to an existing union type) and class types make it easy to derive new class types (but impossible to add new methods to an existing class hierarchy). These are the two forms of extensibility required in practice. The ability to extend in both directions simultaneously without sacrificing static type safety is just an academic curiosity, IME.

Incidentally, the most elegant way to provide this kind of extensibility that I have seen is to sacrifice type safety and use so-called "rule-based programming". Mathematica does this. For example, a function to compute the symbolic derivative of an expression that is an integer literal, variable or addition may be written in Mathematica like this:

```
D[_Integer, _] := 0
D[x_Symbol, x_] := 1
D[_Symbol, _] := 0
D[f_ + g_, x_] := D[f, x] + D[g, x]
```

We can retrofit support for multiplication like this:

```
D[f_ g_, x_] := f D[g, x] + g D[f, x]
```

and we can add a new function to evaluate an expression like this:

```
E[n_Integer] := n
E[f_ + g_] = E[f] + E[g]
```

To me, this is far more elegant than any of the solutions written in languages like OCaml, Haskell and Scala but, of course, it is not type safe.