# where is sprintfn gone, in F#?

Tags: f#

There are a few pages that mention `sprintfn` in F#.

One of them is a classic: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-in-60-seconds/

But also here, in an answer by Tomas: [Is the "expression problem" solvable in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863112/is-the-expression-problem-solvable-in-f)

However, I can't seem to be able to use it, it looks like it is not defined. Was it removed from the language?

Comment: There's `sprintf`, but not `sprintfn`. What should the point be with `sprintfn`, as the `n` "stands for" "new line"?

Comment: I think the authors probably just had `printf/printfn` in mind when they wrote this.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there never was an `sprintfn` function, but you can create one, of course. Just use `kprintf` and add the newline in the continuation function.

Comment: I find myself typing sprintfn sometimes, so it looks like I could use it :D I guess others that typed docs, etc felt the same way

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, this function is not available anywhere in the stndard F# library today. Given that we have `printf/printfn`, this sounds like a possibly useful addition. You can certainly define it yourself:

```
let sprintfn fmt = 
  Printf.kprintf (fun s -> s + "\n") fmt

sprintfn "Hello %s!" "world"
```

To answer the question where is it gone - I'm not entirely sure this ever existed. My SO answer is only a sketch and not an executable code, so that may just have been an error. The code shared from Scott uses the function in a comment only.

There was certainly an old Visual Studio "F# Script File" template (I can find a copy on my machine from circa 2010), which had the following:

```
/// A string computed using the 'sprintfn' string layout function
let stringE = sprintf "stringC = %s, stringD.Length = %d" stringC stringD.Length
```

If you [do a search on all of GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=F%23&p=1&q=sprintfn&type=Code), you'll find a few references to this, but most of those are just copies of the code from Scott. There are a few libraries that define their own `sprintfn` function, but not very many.

Amazingly, you can also [download the F# code drop from November 2010 from WebArchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20121102133844/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18706) and this also has no mention of `sprintfn`. So, I really think it never existed :-).

Comment: To add to that, I think these functions are inspired by their C++ equivalents, and C++ doesn't have `sprintfn` either. It's just a guess, but I think it only exists for console printing because that's just such a common use case (printing a line to the console with `printfn`).

Comment: I use the sprintf(n) to send logs to a remote system, so it is a similar use case to the printfn; but yes, it's something small that I guess would have made sense to have